# Mongoose: How to extract arrays in subdocuments to a single array in the parent document

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, mern

An Express server using Mongoose returns the following JSON from the database in one of its routes:

```
{
  "gradeLevel": 12,
  "classes": [
    {
      "className": "A",
      "students": [
        "student1", "student2","student3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "className": "B",
      "students": [
        "student4", "student5","student6"
      ]
    },
    {
      "className": "C",
      "students": [
        "student7", "student8","student9"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the client, I'd like to be able to for example efficiently check if a student is in **any** of the class subdocuments in the parent document. The following are the solutions I've conceived, but am not sure which is best practice:

1. When a student is pushed to class subdocument, push the student to the parent's `students` field as well.
2. Add a new field in the model's toJSON transformation to compile all the students.
3. Use vanilla Javascript in the client to extract all students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was at this problem too. But to tackle this you need a separate collection called `allStudents` for example where the schema of it is as follows
`{ nameOfStudent: 'String' className: 'String' }`

then aggregate it accordingly with subdoucment. So that wherever you push a new student into `allStudents` with the `className` mentioned it will be pushed to the students subdocument of the respective className.

Comment: Thank you for this, is this ideal in terms of performance since it would take more time to add and remove students?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect the performance much cause it just filters and adds it once and whenever required is taken from the subdocument

Comment: please approve this answer if your issue is solved :)

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helps. I'll approve this and add another solution which uses Javascript's `some()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Querying with dot notation, like

```
.find({"classes.students":"student8"})
```

will check the `students` field of each object in the `classes` array, returning the documents containing the specific student in any class.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, where should I use this query? I'm not sure if I can/should use Mongoose code in the React client.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers given. Just sharing another solution using vanilla Javascript that might be of use to those in similar situations:

```
  checkStudent = (batch, student) => {
    let result = null
    const inClass = (cls) => {
      if (cls.students.includes(student)) {
        result = cls
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
    batch.classes.some(inClass)
    return result
  }
```